# Canceling call as the malloc lock is held so it isn't safe to call the runtime - in iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, gdb

When I was converting a char * to NSString in my App, I got this strage error:

Canceling call as the malloc lock is held so it isn't safe to call the runtime

The  GDB gave me the below information.

**Canceling call as the malloc lock is held so it isn't safe to call the runtime.
Issue the command:
    set objc-non-blocking-mode off 
to override this check if you are sure your call doesn't use the malloc libraries or the ObjC runtime.**

Why this happens?

The code I used here is:

```
objcResponse.desc = [NSString stringWithCString:info->desc encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

objCResponse is an Objective C entity and info is an C++ entity (class).

**Other information:**

I am using NSOperationQueue in my App to make calls to SOAP Web service.
I also get the below error if I used this code:

```
 char *value = info->desc;
    objcResponse.desc = [NSString stringWithCString:value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know that the problem occurred due to the contents of info->desc being NULL.

I did a check for NULL and convert them directly to NSString only if info->desc  is not equal to NULL.